# Why are density values coming very large when sampling from exponential using copula?

Tags: r, mode, exponential, probability-density

Consider the code

```
library("copula")
mycop=normalCopula(param=c(0.55),dim=2)#rho=0.55
mymvd=mvdc(copula=mycop,margins=c("exp","exp"),paramMargins=list(list(rate=1),list(rate=1)))
xy=rMvdc(5000,mymvd)
den=dMvdc(xy,mymvd)
mode=xy[which.max(den),]
mode.den=max(den)
mode
mode.den
```

The mode value is alright its coming as(0.0017,0.00147) as mode lies at (0,0) for exponential distributions. But the density at mode is coming to be 26.11 which is vague. Can anyone tell me why is that happening? or is there anything I am missing out?

Comment: What would you expect the density to be?  If the exponentials were uncorrelated, it would be 1, but it should be higher because of the correlation.  I don't know how much higher, so I think this is really a question for the stats site...

Comment: Yes. Thank you.